# MySQL Join - Retrieve Left Table Rows only if all the Right Table Rows satisfies the WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables (Table A & Table B) in which a single parent row in 'Table A' will have multiple rows in 'Table B'. I have to retrieve rows from 'Table A', only if all the child rows in 'Table B' satisfies a WHERE clause.

**Table A**

```
id     INT
name    VARCHAR
gender  VARCHAR
```

**Table B**

```
id        INT
table_A_id INT
condition  INT
```

Now I have to fetch the rows of 'Table A' for those which all the child rows in 'Table B' satisfies the `WHERE` clause `'condition=100'`.

Comment: Remove the incorrect tag and review the link https://www.guru99.com/joins.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THis will do it:

```
select * from TableA A JOIN TableA B ON B.table_A_id = A.id 
where not exists (select 1 from TableB B where B.table_A_id = A.id and condition  <> 100)
```

Comment: This will also return rows from TableA with ids that do not exist in TableB.

Comment: @forpas Yes. As you mentioned, this will return rows from TableA with ids that do not exist in TableB. To overcome that I made a JOIN from Table A to Table B, thereby removing rows which doesn't have child rows in Table B

Comment: @Jai so what you did is scan tableB twice.

Comment: @forpas Yes It scans Table B twice. Is it better to have a IN query with ids fetched from second table. Is that approach better than this ?

Comment: The ids are fetched with 1 scan of tableb.

Comment: @Jai did you update this wrong answer with your code and accepted it? This is something I haven't seen before!!!

Answer (score 2):

This query:

```
select table_A_id
from tableb
group by table_A_id
having sum(case when condition = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
```

returns all the `table_A_id`s in tableb that meet the condition.
You can use it with IN like this:

```
select * 
from tablea 
where id in (
  select table_A_id
  from tableb
  group by table_A_id
  having sum(case when condition = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
)
```

Or you can join the subquery:

```
select a.* 
from tablea a inner join (
  select table_A_id
  from tableb
  group by table_A_id
  having sum(case when condition = 100 then 1 else 0 end) = count(*)
) b on b.table_A_id = a.id
```

Note that for MySql the HAVING clause can be simplified to this:

```
having sum(condition = 100) = count(*)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would simply recommend:

```
select a.*
from TableA a 
where not exists (select 1
                  from TableB B
                  where B.table_A_id = A.id and
                        condition <> 100
                 );
```

If `condition` can be `NULL`, then you want:

```
where not exists (select 1
                  from TableB B
                  where B.table_A_id = A.id and
                        (condition <> 100 or condition is null)
                 );
```

Comment: But this would also return rows from Table A which doesn't have child in Table B

Comment: @Jai . . . And that satisfies the condition that you specified:  "I have to retrieve rows from 'Table A', only if all the child rows in 'Table B' satisfies a WHERE clause."  If there are no child rows, then the condition is satisfied.